# python スクレイピング　営業時間の取得

Tags: python, web-scraping

某有名グルメサイトのスクレイピングをpythonで試みていますが上手くいきません。
TAB LOG

URL毎に
・店名
・電話番号
・住所
・営業時間
を取得する予定です。

当初場所をCSSセレクターで指定していたものの、ページによって位置が若干変わってしまうようです。
おそらく文字列（”営業時間”）を含むタグを探して、その中身を出力？のようなことでできる気がするのですが、いくら調べてもやり方がわかりません。

以下は参考までに、現時点での営業時間を取得する部分のコードですが、気にしないで貰ってかまわないです。

平日と休日を分けて出力するのを意図しています。
tablinkにURLを入れます

ご教授宜しくお願いします

import csv
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def left(text, n):
return text[:n]
def right(text, n):
return text[n:]
def get_dotwlefts(tablink):
response = requests.get(tablink)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
dotwfound = soup.select_one("#contents-rstdata > div.rstinfo-table > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td > p")
if dotwfound is not None:
dotw = dotwfound.text
if dotwfound is None:
dotw = ""
m = re.search(r"[土|【土|[土・日【日|土・日|日祝|土日祝|日・祝|[日・祝|土・日・祝|土日|土、日|[金|【金|[日|金/土", dotw, flags=re.DOTALL)
y = m.start() if m else None
dotwlefts = left(dotw,y)
dotwrights = right(dotw,y)
if dotwlefts==dotwrights:
dotwrights = ""
return dotwlefts 
def get_dotwrights(tablink):
response = requests.get(tablink)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
dotwfound = soup.select_one("#contents-rstdata > div.rstinfo-table > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td > p")
if dotwfound is not None:
dotw = dotwfound.text
if dotwfound is None:
dotw = ""
m = re.search(r"[土|【土|[土・日【日|土・日|日祝|土日祝|日・祝|[日・祝|土・日・祝|土日|土、日|[金|【金|[日|金/土", dotw, flags=re.DOTALL)
y = m.start() if m else None
dotwlefts = left(dotw,y)
dotwrights = right(dotw,y)
if dotwlefts==dotwrights:
dotwrights = ""
return dotwrights

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12203323352

Comment: @IHL さん、スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　Python ではインデントが意味を持ちますが、質問文中のプログラムは (Markdown の時点でも) インデントが失われてしまっています。もう一度プログラムをコピー＆ペーストして頂けませんでしょうか？　また、プログラム部分を範囲選択した後エディタ上部の `{}` ボタンを押すことで、コードブロックとして装飾することもできますのでお試しください :)

Comment: スクレイピングという内容的に、取得先のページが分からないことには的確な回答を得ることは困難そうです。

Comment: こんな記事がありますのでご参考に。[PythonのBeautifulSoupを利用して食べログのラーメン屋情報をスクレイピング](http://tadashi000000.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-37.html)

Comment: 有難うございます、コードは後ほど貼り直します、

Comment: ラーメン屋をスクレイピングした記事は大変参考になったのですが、soup_tr.th.stringのところでエラーが出て動かなかったのと、仕組みが把握できませんでした。

Comment: 取得先のページは任意の食べログのページです。例えば　https://tabelog.com/tokyo/A1303/A130301/13182370/　です

Answer (score 0, accepted):

紹介先情報を元にPython3で作ってみました。
それぞれの項目をprint()で表示しているので、保存や加工したい場合は別途処理を行ってください。
「soup_tr.th.stringのところでエラーが出た」のはencoding関連の問題と思われます。

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
newlines = re.compile(r'\n{2,}')

def scrape_info(soup_table):
  """
  基本情報の抽出
  """
  global newlines
  soup_telnum = soup_table.find("strong", class_="rstinfo-table__tel-num")
  soup_address = soup_table.find("p", class_="rstinfo-table__address")
  soup_tr_list = soup_table.find_all("tr")
  for soup_tr in soup_tr_list:
    if soup_tr.th.string in {"店名", "営業時間"}:
      item = ''
      if (soup_tr.th.string == "店名"):
        item = soup_tr.td.get_text().strip()
      else:
        item = newlines.sub("\n", soup_tr.td.get_text("\n").strip())
      print(item)
  print(soup_telnum.get_text())
  print(soup_address.get_text())
  return

def scrape_item(item_url):
  """
  個別情報ページのパーシング
  """
  r = requests.get(item_url)
  if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
    print(f"error:not found{item_url}")
    return
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
  soup_table = soup.find("table", class_="rstinfo-table__table")
  scrape_info(soup_table)
  return

scrape_item('https://tabelog.com/tokyo/A1303/A130301/13182370/')
```